# Why Raspberry Pi3 randomly receives cloud to device messages from Azure IoT Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, raspberry-pi3, iot

I built the azure-iot-sdk-c on Raspberry Pi3 Model B, and created an Azure Function on the cloud, I am trying with the two IoT client sample codes provided in the SDK, i.e. iothub_ll_telemetry_sample and the iothub_ll_c2d_sample, to complete a message loop from Pi3 (device) to cloud and back from cloud to Pi3(device). The iothub_ll_telemetry_sample sends message up to cloud from Pi3 successfully, but the iothub_ll_c2d_sample shows random receiving or no receiving of "hello world" messages.

The Azure Function in C# or Javascript follows the tutorial examples, which I assume no problem.

I am just wondering if I missing something here, or not doing it correctly.

Comment: please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Does your Azure Function work as expected when you test it in isolation?

Comment: @KatyShimizu I suppose in isolation means locally on PC? I did not do that, since it's basically tutorial example Function, do you have a link i can follow to test it in isolation?

Comment: I meant testing your function where it's currently deployed to rule it out (or identify it) as the fault in your message loop. (Testing locally before deployment isn't a bad idea either.)

Comment: no, i do not think any problem with the Function, as just copied from tutorial examples.

Comment: could you provide a link to the tutorial?

Comment: @Thomas, one tutorial here for C2D messages https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-node-node-c2d